# Several tableview in one viewcontroller and each tableview has different swipeActions. how do i manage them?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

My app is crashing after I do a leadswipe action. and then try to do a trail swipe. I get this error "Exception: "Actions view not added to view hierarchy after calling -swipeActionController:insertActionsView:forItemAtIndexPath: on <UITableView: 0x7fa80b859400; frame = (20 390; 335 150); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x6000035c1080>; layer = <CALayer: 0x600003bd59e0>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {335, 0}; adjustedContentInset: {0, 0, 0, 0}; dataSource: <SlideInTransition.HomeViewController: 0x7fa80b508070>>""
I have two tableviews, and two array one to each tableview.
here is my code for the contextual actions.

```
    // Leading Swipe Action
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
        if tableView == homeTableView {
        let task = todaysTasks[indexPath.row]
        let complete = markCompleteToday(at: indexPath)
        if (task.value(forKey: "isComplete") as! Bool == false){
                return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [complete])
            
}
        } else if tableView == tomorrowDeadlinesTV{
            let task = tomorrowTasks[indexPath.row]
            let complete = markCompleteTomorrow(at: indexPath)
            if (task.value(forKey: "isComplete") as! Bool == false){
            
                   return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [complete])

            }
        }
        return         UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [])

    }
    
    
    // Mark as Completed Task
    func markCompleteToday(at: IndexPath) -> UIContextualAction {
        
        let df = DateFormatter()
        df.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy" // assigning the date format
        let now = df.string(from: Date()) // extracting the date with the given format
        let cell = homeTableView.cellForRow(at: at) as! CustomCell
        let task = todaysTasks[at.row]
        let completeActionImage = UIImage(named: "AddTask")?.withTintColor(.white)
        let action = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "Complete") { (action, view, completion) in
            
            task.setValue(!(task.value(forKey: "isComplete") as! Bool), forKey: "isComplete")
            
            self.homeTableView.cellForRow(at: at)?.backgroundColor = task.value(forKey: "isComplete") as! Bool ? Colors.greencomplete : .white
            cell.backgroundColor = Colors.greencomplete
            cell.labelsToWhite()
            
            task.setValue("Finished " + now, forKey: "date")
   
            do {
                try
                context.save()
                

            } catch {
                print("Markcomplete save error")
            }
            
            //            cell.displayIcons(task: task)
            completion(true)
            
        }
        
        //action.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "AddTask")
        action.image = completeActionImage
        action.backgroundColor = Colors.greencomplete
        return action
    }
    func markCompleteTomorrow(at: IndexPath) -> UIContextualAction {
         
         let df = DateFormatter()
         df.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy" // assigning the date format
         let now = df.string(from: Date()) // extracting the date with the given format
         let cell = tomorrowDeadlinesTV.cellForRow(at: at) as! CustomCell
         let task = tomorrowTasks[at.row]
         let completeActionImage = UIImage(named: "AddTask")?.withTintColor(.white)
         let action = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "Complete") { (action, view, completion) in
             
             task.setValue(!(task.value(forKey: "isComplete") as! Bool), forKey: "isComplete")
             
             self.tomorrowDeadlinesTV.cellForRow(at: at)?.backgroundColor = task.value(forKey: "isComplete") as! Bool ? Colors.greencomplete : .white
             cell.backgroundColor = Colors.greencomplete
             cell.labelsToWhite()
             
             task.setValue("Finished " + now, forKey: "date")
    
             do {
                 try
                 context.save()
                 

             } catch {
                 print("Markcomplete save error")
             }
             
             //            cell.displayIcons(task: task)
             completion(true)
             
         }
         
         action.image = completeActionImage
         action.backgroundColor = Colors.greencomplete
         return action
     }
    
    // Trailing Swipe Actions
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {

        if tableView == homeTableView {
            let task = todaysTasks[indexPath.row]
            let important = changeTextAction(at: indexPath, table: self.homeTableView, arr: todaysTasks)
            let delete    = deleteActionToday(at: indexPath)
            
        if task.value(forKey: "isComplete") as? Bool == true {
            return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [delete])
        } else {
            return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [delete,important])
        }
        } else if tableView == tomorrowDeadlinesTV {
            let task = tomorrowTasks[indexPath.row]
                let important = changeTextAction(at: indexPath, table: self.tomorrowDeadlinesTV, arr: tomorrowTasks)
                let delete    = deleteActionTomorrow(at: indexPath)
            if task.value(forKey: "isComplete") as? Bool == true {
                return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [delete])
            } else {
                return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [delete,important])
            }
        } else {
        return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [])
        }
        }
    
    
    // Mark as Important Action
    // notification toggle
    func toggleTaskReminder(at: IndexPath) -> UIContextualAction{
       // let reminderImage = UIImage(named: "")
        let action = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "Notification") { (action, view, completion) in
            
        }
        return action
    }
    func changeTextAction(at: IndexPath , table:UITableView, arr:[NSManagedObject]) -> UIContextualAction{
        let editActionImage = UIImage(named: "Edit")?.withTintColor(.white)
        let action = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "Important") { (action, view, completion) in
            self.changeTaskText(at: at, tableview: table, arr: arr)
            completion(true)
        }
        action.image = editActionImage
        action.backgroundColor = .purple
        return action
    }
    

    func deleteActionToday(at: IndexPath) -> UIContextualAction {
        let deleteActionImage = UIImage(named: "Delete")?.withTintColor(.white)
        let action = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive , title: "Delete") { (action, view, completion) in
            let objectToDelete = todaysTasks.remove(at: at.row)
            context.delete(objectToDelete)
            self.homeTableView.deleteRows(at: [at], with: .automatic)
            do {
            try
            context.save()
            } catch {
            print("Problem while saving")
            }
            completion(true)
        }
        action.image = deleteActionImage
        action.backgroundColor = Colors.reddelete
        self.loadTasks(sort: .none)
        homeTableView.reloadData()
        tomorrowDeadlinesTV.reloadData()
        return action
    }
    func deleteActionTomorrow(at: IndexPath) -> UIContextualAction {
        let deleteActionImage = UIImage(named: "Delete")?.withTintColor(.white)
        let action = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive , title: "Delete") { (action, view, completion) in
            let objectToDelete = tomorrowTasks.remove(at: at.row)
            context.delete(objectToDelete)
            self.tomorrowDeadlinesTV.deleteRows(at: [at], with: .automatic)
            do {
            try
            context.save()
            } catch {
            print("Problem while saving")
            }
            completion(true)
        }
        action.image = deleteActionImage
        action.backgroundColor = Colors.reddelete
        self.loadTasks(sort: .none)
        homeTableView.reloadData()
        tomorrowDeadlinesTV.reloadData()
        return action
    }


    

    func loadTasks(sort: [NSSortDescriptor]?){
        tomorrowTasks.removeAll()
        todaysTasks.removeAll()
        let tomorrow = DateComponents(year: currentDateComponents.year, month: currentDateComponents.month, day: currentDateComponents.day! + 1)
        let dateTomorrow = Calendar.current.date(from: tomorrow)!
        let df = DateFormatter()
        df.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy" // assigning the date format
        let now = df.string(from: Date())
        let tomorrowDateString = df.string(from: dateTomorrow)
        print("TOMORROW'S DATE IS : " , tomorrowDateString)
        
        let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Tasks")
        if let sort = sort{
        request.sortDescriptors = sort
        }
        do {
            let allTasks = try context.fetch(request) as! [NSManagedObject]
            for item in allTasks {
            if item.value(forKey: "date") as! String == now {
                todaysTasks.append(item)
                }
            if item.value(forKey: "date") as! String == tomorrowDateString {
                tomorrowTasks.append(item)
                }
            }
          print("loadTasks() fired!")
        } catch let error as NSError {
          print("Could not fetch. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }

    }
    
    func changeTaskText(at:IndexPath , tableview: UITableView , arr:[NSManagedObject]){
        
        let cell = tableview.cellForRow(at: at) as! CustomCell
        let task = arr[at.row]
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Edit Task", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addTextField()
        let submitAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Submit", style: .default) { (UIAlertAction) in
            task.setValue(alert.textFields![0].text!, forKey: "name")
            cell.setTask(task: task)
            do {
                try context.save()
                self.allTaskViewController.tableView.reloadData()
            } catch {
                print("Edit Fail")
            }
            print(task)
        }
        alert.addAction(submitAction)
        present(alert,animated: true)
    }
```